# How to set the javac compiler flags to generate 1.7 bytecode?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to follow the instructions on [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Java) page to install Google App Engine on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am stuck on the  third point in 'Installing on Linux' which is:

> The App Engine Java SDK requires Java 7 bytecode level. You can use either Java 7 or Java 8; be sure to set the javac compiler flags to generate 1.7 bytecode:
>
> -source 1.7 -target 1.7

What I have tried is:

```
javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7
```

But this gives me the error

> javac: no source files 
>   use -help for a list of possible options

The command given below also give the same error

```
javac -source 1.7
```

However `javac -target 1.7` gives the following error

> javac: target release 1.7 conflicts with default source release 1.8

Any advice on how to tackle this problem would be highly appreciated.

Further information:

`javac -version` gives `javac 1.8.0_92` as output.

`java -version` gives this output:

> java version "1.8.0_92"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: You have to add the class you want to compile to your first Statement, as the error message says "javac: no source files"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the `-source 1.7 -target 1.7` options when you actually are compiling code. For example:

```
javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 MyProgram.java
```

will compile the source file `MyProgram.java` and produce a Java 7-compatible class file `MyProgram.class`.

It's not like you execute `javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7` once and then some setting is remembered somewhere so that from then on it works in Java 7 mode (which is how you seem to think it works).

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the jdk version to compile with and jvm version to compatible with but did not mention source file which actually needs to be compiled

```
  javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 yourSource.java
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html for details